# Using Powershell To Check Home Folder Permissions For All AD users

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

How can I check home folder permissions for all AD users via Powershell?

Here's my script so far:

```
    $MyUser = Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "*"'

    foreach ($User in $MyUser)

    {

    (Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\$MyUser).access | ft 
    IdentityRerference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited -Auto

    }
```

I get a long, long error message (one message for each user) that says,
"ObjectNotFound (:) [Get-ACL] ItemNotFoundException
Get-ACL_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft,Powershell.Commands.Get-ACLCommand."

I can get it to work, but only when I run it for one user at a time this:

```
    (Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\barry.scott).access | ft 
    IdentityRerference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited -Auto
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
    $MyUser = Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "$_.GivenName.$_.Surname*"'

    foreach ($User in $MyUser)

    {

    (Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\$MyUser).access | ft 
    IdentityRerference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited -Auto

    }
```

In this form I get no output and no errors.

This is for Server 2012.  Any thoughts?

I hope this makes sense - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You currently have

```
(Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\$MyUser).access
```

You probably want

```
(Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\$User.SamAccountName).access
```

Complete Example

```
$MyUser = Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "*"'

foreach ($User in $MyUser)
{
(Get-ACL -path \\NameOfMyServer\home\$($User.SamAccountName)).access | ft IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited -Auto
}
```

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much David!  You are amazing!

Comment: You’re welcome. The $($object.property) trips me up. It’s hard to describe it in a way that you can search for it also. Tricky.